# How do you use __init__.py?

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to learn how the `__init__.py` file works for packaging and calling modules from different directories.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
init_test\
__init__.py
     a\
        aaa.py
     b\
        bbb.py
```

in `aaa.py` there is a function called `test`

`bbb.py` looks like this:

```
import init_test.a.aaa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_test.a.aaa.test()
```

but this gives me `ImportError: No module named a.aaa`

What am I doing wrong? I've tried doing the same basic thing from a module above the package structure as opposed to inside the package and that did not work either? My `__init__.py`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an empty `__init__.py` into a. Then a is recognized as a sub package of init_test and can be imported. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Then change `import init_test.a.aaa` to `import ..a.aaa` and it should work. This is -- as Achim says -- a relative import, see http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328

If you really want to run `bbb.py`, you have to put init_test/ on your python path, e.g.

```
import sys
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(dirname, "../.."))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, ".")
import init_test.a.aaa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inittest.a.aaa.test()
```

And then you can start

```
python init_test/b/bbb.y
```

or if you are inside b/

```
python bbb.py
```

Comment: import ..a.aaa gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: argh. That does not work, because you run bbb.py inside your package ! Why do you do that ?

Comment: I tried one outside of the package and it worked. Thanks. Ugh. This whole python multiple files stuff is bullcrap. Why didn't they just set it up similar to C header file linking style...

Comment: It is no bullcrap if you use packages in the intended way. If you want to test a method in a package, you put the test script outside the package as others would use the package too. Then relative imports work. Manipulating sys.path is a last resort but not the recommended way.

Comment: No, I realize that might not be the intended way to use a package, but I just mean I wish python would have simple relative path module includes...

Answer (score 7):

You also need to have __init__.py in a and b directories

For your example to work first you should add your base directory to the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../..')

import init_test.a.aaa
...
```

Comment: This is not enough. Running bbb.py inside b/ will still fail.

Comment: But then you only can start it if you run python inside init_test/b.

Comment: yes but that wasn't part of the question :) if it should be called from the base directory then your answer would work

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it should work in all situations, the question gave no information how bbb.py is started...

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` needs to be in **all** folders that you want to use as modules. In your case, this means `init_test/a` and `init_test/b` too.